# how to take input from a text file in an array in codelocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I am trying to fill an array using data from a text file. I have tried data file handling but it is not working in code blocks. This is the code I wrote and it is showing me either 0 or some completely different number from that present in the file.

```
`//all variables not declared over here have been declared globally.This is just a part of //my code
int main()
{
    fstream f;
    f.open("IntegerArray.txt",ios::in);
    for(z=0;z<100000;z++)
    {
         cout<<f;
         f>>arr[z];
         cout<<arr[z];
         getch();
    }
    f.close();`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    fstream f;
    f.open( "IntegerArray.txt", ios::in );

    int arr[100000];
    for ( int z = 0; z < 100000; z++ )
    {
        f >> arr[z];
        // Check if file stream is OK
        // Will return false if end-of-file reached
        if ( !f )
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << arr[z];

        getchar();
    }

    f.close();
}
```